# Embedding a rails view within a view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

Rails noob here.  I'm attempting to create create single-page scrolling site [similar to this](http://pervolo.com/en/#what-we-do) ...but, you know, not nearly as attractive :-)

Anyway, I've got my javascript working however I've developed much of the content (contact form, about us page etc etc) in different views which are hanging out in various `html.erb` files.  Rather than cut and paste the contents of each into a single `home.html.erb`, I was wondering if there was a clean way to just embed the content from each view into my homepage view.  Something like this:

```
<h1>My awesome homepage!</h1>
<div>
    <div id="about">
    <%= put_page_here page=about_us %>
    </div>
    <div id="our_product">
    <%= put_page_here page=about_us %>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
    <%= put_page_here page=contact %>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you would recommend going about this entirely differently, please let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= render partial:"shared/contact_us", locals:{variable:value} %>
```

Note that it will look for a view in `app/views/shared/_contact_us.html.erb` - notice the `_` before the view. Pass the variables the view needs in through `locals`. More information on passing variables around [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).